# decreasing gravity in udk?

Tags: unreal-development-kit

I am trying to create a mod in udk by adding jetpacks, so I need the players to jump very high, I can't figure out how to do this in unreal script. Can someone explain how to do this or point me to a good tutorial. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by taking a look at the code for the low gravity mutator that is present in Unreal Tournament 2004.

Comment: If you accepted the answer, please share result here ! this is a Question-Answer site... Not Question-Reference !

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to change the jump height I would recommend changing the Pawn's JumpZ instead of changing the gravity on the whole map. Vehicles floating off may be fun for a moment, but it can mess up gameplay. If you change JumpZ you might also want to change the fall damage, so you don't die just from jumping.